# flash as3 movieClip loader doesn't load in numerical sequence

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, loader, movieclip

I am loading an array of movie clips and adding them to the stage with flash as3, but the problem is that the movie clips are added to the stage as soon as they finish loading, and not in order of there position in the array, so the order on screen appears messed up. How do I ensure that they are added to the stage in the same order that their references exist in the URL? Here is my code:

```
var currentLoaded:int = 0;

function loadThumbs(){
    for (var i in project_array){
        var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(project_array[i].project_thumb));
        thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
    }
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
    project_array[currentLoaded].projectThumb.thumbHolder.addChild(e.target.content);
    admin.slideHolder.addChild(project_array[currentLoaded].projectThumb);
    currentLoaded++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was just typing the same solution...
to Load in some specific order, you have to make it recursive.
You may try the loadermax library from greensock. Is rock solid, fast and lightweight.
Besides that very easy to use and you can set the ammount of parallel loading treads.
you can find it [here](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/)

Answer (score 1):

Assets might load faster than others, so something like this might help...

```
  function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
      project_array[currentLoaded].projectThumb.thumbHolder.addChild(e.target.content);
      currentLoaded++;
      if(currentLoaded>=project_array.length){
        addAssetsToStage();
      }
    }

    function addAssetsToStage():void{
      for(var i:int=0;i<project_array.length;i++)
      {
        admin.slideHolder.addChild(project_array[i].projectThumb);
      }   
    }
```

Comment: That wouldn't quite work either, currentLoaded is just a counter. Adding e.target.content as the child of project_array[currentLoaded] would just assign things in the order they were loaded still. What it needs to be is project_array[i], but we've lost scope of what i is. I was thinking of adding thumbLoader to the proper array object in the loadThumbs function, but then I'm not sure how to reference its content. Something like this: project_array[i].addChild(thumbLoader); in loadThumbs and admin.slideHolder.addChild(project_array[i].thumbLoader.content); in addThumbs

Comment: scratch that - can't add a loader as a child, it lookslike

Comment: @mheavens - this loads all clips, then adds them in order needed. Best solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose this works - but if anyone figures out a way to do this without waiting for each previous image to load before starting another load, please let me know!

```
    var currentLoaded:int = 0;

function loadThumbs(){
    if (currentLoaded < project_array.length){
        var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(project_array[currentLoaded].project_thumb));
        thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
    }
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
    project_array[currentLoaded].projectThumb.thumbHolder.addChild(e.target.content);
    admin.slideHolder.addChild(project_array[currentLoaded].projectThumb);
    currentLoaded++;
    loadThumbs();
}
```